# SSL Certificate add failed, Error: 183 Cannot create a file when that file already exists on VSTS

Tags: ssl, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am implementing continuous deployment with VSTS, I configure my website with HTTP & HTTPS bindings with a certificate installed on my server. When I run the deploy suite and start the creation of the website I am getting this error:

**SSL Certificate add failed, Error: 183
Cannot create a file when that file already exists.**

The site does not exist and the certificate configured for https binding it is installed on the server. I don't know why the process is trying to create the certificate, is there a way to tell VSTS to use an existing certificate?

For more information I have configured an IIS Web App Manage with EnableIIS option enabled with Create or Update action, add binding option enabled and SSL certificate thumbprint configured from Thumbprint on details options.

This is my server configuration:

- Windows Server 2012 R2
- IIS v 8.5.9600.16384

Thank you.

Comment: Can you share the detailed deployment logs?

Comment: Solved!!! it was my bad, i was working with an agent from another server and the deploy process was trying to create that certificate. Thanks

Comment: @user3865527 Would you mind adding an answer to your question with some detail about how you resolved the issue? FYI this question is top search result for "SSL Certificate add failed, Error: 183 Cannot create a file when that file already exists".

Comment: In our case, we're using Let's Encrypt and I found that for each renewal of the certificate, the thumbprint changes.  Once I updated my deployment step to use the correct thumbprint, I stopped getting this error and the deployment was successful.

Answer (score 5):

If you have recently renewed your ssl certificate, go through this [article](https://medium.com/@whuysentruit/simplify-certificate-renewal-in-azure-devops-68b7d916dcd1), you have to add your new certificate hash thumbprint to the binding step in your pipeline.

Comment: That article you're linking actually shows exactly the right dialogs and stuff, but the "require SNI" checkbox that actually addresses the issue in question is neither mentioned, nor checked. Other than that, it's a good reference. However, links tend to break, so you may want to consider including more information in your answer, rather than relying on a 3:rd party.

Answer (score 4):

I was trying to bind two different https websites to two different certificates. I used Server Name Indication (SNI) to fix this issue.

[Related ServerFault question](https://serverfault.com/q/856942)

Comment: This solution works in Azure DevOps as well, but the "require SNI" check-box is a bit hard to find, hidden deep inside the pipeline root "add bindings" dialog (using the IIS Website configuration type).